# Could not run Hauwei E173 on 12.10 using NetworkManager (even from trunk)

Tags: 12.10, network-manager, usb-modem, modem-manager

I am trying to run Huawei E173 device on Ubuntu 12.10. First of all I have tried running it on raw Ubuntu (installed via Wubi) without any changes. Device was detected at `lsusb` as `Bus 003 Device 004: ID 12d1:1c05 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173s 3G broadband stick (modem on)` but I can't find it at any /dev/ttyU* path (as I expected at ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1...). Then I tried using trunk NetworkManager and ModemManager, same results. Device was listed on `lsusb` (that mean usb-modechange is working correctly).

Here is some output that might help You to investigate problem with me:

**Syslog output:**

```
Mar 31 16:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.127008] usb 3-1: >new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Mar 31 16:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.377948] usb 3-1: >New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1c05
Mar 31 16:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.377954] usb 3-1: >New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Mar 31 16:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.377958] usb 3-1: >Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Mar 31 16:23:28 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.377961] usb 3-1: >Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Mar 31 16:23:28 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1"
Mar 31 16:23:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.561484] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 16:23:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.561681] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 16:23:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.561880] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 16:23:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.562033] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 16:23:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.562168] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 16:23:29 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Mar 31 16:23:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1297.562268] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
```

I have also found something strange, after *first* plug in Huawei E173 device I found some *extra* logs (from usbcore):

```
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.607001] usb 3-1: >new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.626461] usb 3-1: >New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1c05
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.626467] usb 3-1: >New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.626471] usb 3-1: >Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.626474] usb 3-1: >Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:05:00.0/usb3/3-1"
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.668930] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.669473] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.669490] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.669502] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.669518] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.681131] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.681205] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.681266] usb 3-1: >bad CDC descriptors
Mar 31 17:03:37 ubuntu kernel: [  109.681302] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_wlan
```

**Edit:** I have same error (usb 2-3: bad CDC descriptor) while running latest netinstall debian.

Comment: did you tried installing its software?

Comment: what software do you mean @Sreevisakh? Mobilepartner for linux? Yes, I have tried with ubuntu and Mobilepartner with no effects. I am thinking about some E173 device mode, mabey something get locked, but why I still could use device on Osx?

Comment: in my system i can only use either network manager or mobile partner at a time.it gives lot of errors sometimes won;t detect sometimes won't connect. But most of the time mobile partner will detect after a restart

Comment: In my case MobilePartner wont work :(